# Hive on Spark: Insufficient resources

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Following this [tutorial](http://hadooptutorials.info/2017/10/09/part-5-using-spark-as-execution-engine-for-hive/) and configured Spark as execution engine for Hive. However it hangs with each simple query

I tried to

```
set spark.executor.memory = 1g;
set spark.driver.memory = 1g;
set spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead = 2048;
set spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead = 1024;
```

but that didn't solve my problem.

In the Dashboard I can see: Alive Workers: 1, Cores in use: 1 Total, 1 Used, 6.8 GB (2 GB Used)

What's weird is that for the running application the core is 0.

Wonder what will solve my problem?

```
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Spark Plan !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO exec.Utilities: PLAN PATH = hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive/alex/d3bc099b-19db-461c-aea6-f29d1c6b05a5/hive_2019-06-25_23-48-37_916_8355031693669842913-1/-mr-10002/23946a9b-f8e0-463b-b92b-61bbb4807b66/map.xml
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO exec.SerializationUtilities: Deserializing MapWork using kryo
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO exec.Utilities: Deserialized plan (via FILE) - name: Map 1 size: 4.14KB
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO io.CombineHiveInputFormat: Total number of paths: 1, launching 1 threads to check non-combinable ones.
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO io.CombineHiveInputFormat: CombineHiveInputSplit creating pool for hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive/alex/d3bc099b-19db-461c-aea6-f29d1c6b05a5/_tmp_space.db/Values__Tmp__Table__1; using filter path hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive/alex/d3bc099b-19db-461c-aea6-f29d1c6b05a5/_tmp_space.db/Values__Tmp__Table__1
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO input.CombineFileInputFormat: DEBUG: Terminated node allocation with : CompletedNodes: 1, size left: 0
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO io.CombineHiveInputFormat: number of splits 1
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO io.CombineHiveInputFormat: Number of all splits 1
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (foreachAsync at RemoteHiveSparkClient.java:351) with 1 output partitions
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (foreachAsync at RemoteHiveSparkClient.java:351)
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at mapPartitionsToPair at MapTran.java:40), which has no missing parents
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 255.5 KB, free 412.5 MB)
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO memory.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 76.6 KB, free 412.4 MB)
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 192.168.0.95:38407 (size: 76.6 KB, free: 413.8 MB)
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at mapPartitionsToPair at MapTran.java:40) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
19/06/25 23:49:13 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
19/06/25 23:49:28 WARN scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
19/06/25 23:49:43 WARN scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I'm using hive-2.3.0 and spark 2.2.0 which should be compatible according to documentation. But I've tried with the newest hive version as well, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Please add more details like your sql query/spark command you're executing. Is it running in `client` or `cluster` mode?

Comment: it is running in client mode. SQL query is a simple insert of 1 record in the hive cli: ```insert into employee values("1","Allen","IT");```
other than that everything is default. for hive I'm using embedded derby db, which works fine in MR mode.